# How to achieve decent color effect and Image Processing in android?

Tags: android, bitmap

i am working on an image editor android app. In  which i need to apply effects to images like [BeFunkey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.befunky.BeFunkyPhotoEditor&hl=en). I have tried so many link like :

[Android - How to apply diffenernt Image Effects on bitmap like sepia, blackand white, blur etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292146/android-how-to-apply-diffenernt-image-effects-on-bitmap-like-sepia-blackand-w)

[Convert a Bitmap to GrayScale in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373860/convert-a-bitmap-to-grayscale-in-android)

[Drawable => grayscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793338/drawable-grayscale)

http://shaikhhamadali.blogspot.in/2013/06/gray-scale-image-in-imageview-android_29.html

http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.ro/p/home.html

http://android.okhelp.cz/hue-color-colored-filter-bitmap-image-android-example/

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html

http://my.fit.edu/~vkepuska/ece5570/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/sdk/samples/android-17/

http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/06/how-to-give-a-posterize-effect-on-imageview/

http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/

[Android apply colorMatrix colorFilter on part of imageView with a mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140501/android-apply-colormatrix-colorfilter-on-part-of-imageview-with-a-mask)

http://activetuts.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/070_effectsTester/Preview/EffectsTester.html  [RGB Effect Calculator]

[Understanding the Use of ColorMatrix and ColorMatrixColorFilter to Modify a Drawable's Hue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354939/understanding-the-use-of-colormatrix-and-colormatrixcolorfilter-to-modify-a-draw)

[Android apply colorMatrix colorFilter on part of imageView with a mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140501/android-apply-colormatrix-colorfilter-on-part-of-imageview-with-a-mask)

http://docs.rainmeter.net/tips/colormatrix-guide (Color Guid)

http://www.adobetutorialz.com/articles/1987/1/Color-Matrix

http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tricks-vignette-image-effect/

[How to move the text view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200850/how-to-move-the-text-view)

[How to save an image in sdcard after applying RGB color filter in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206494/how-to-save-an-image-in-sdcard-after-applying-rgb-color-filter-in-android)

http://www.showandtell-graphics.com/photosketch.html

But Still i cant achieve those effects.

I need to apply Following Effects from [BeFunkey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.befunky.BeFunkyPhotoEditor&hl=en). ::

Instant 1

Viewfinder 2

Cross Process

Summer 2

Old Photo 1

Vintage 3

Lomo Art

Vibrance

TiltShift

But i cant understand what happening exactly in Befunkey. I have tried so much things like use of ColorMatrix in android. I am making diff diff Color Matrix and passing this to following function :

```
public void makingEffects(float[] mat, ImageView img) {

        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));
        ColorFilter colorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);

        img.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
    }
```

But i am getting only color effects but i want effects like BeFunkey. Anybody can help me to achieve this?